# Where SELinux puts it alerts?

Tags: gnome, logging, selinux

where SELinux writes it's alerts?
I searched in google and man but not found this.
I did tail -f to /var/log/secure, but also there, the lines were not added when SELinux policy violation took place.
More of this, anyone remember the toolbar's Gnome applet that blinking at the policy violation?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked */var/log/audit/audit.log*, as explained in **[this document](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-02c04b0b030dd3c3d58bb7acbbcff033505dd3af)**?

I suppose the GNOME applet is *sealert*, a part of **[setroubleshoot](https://fedorahosted.org/setroubleshoot/wiki/SETroubleShoot%20Overview)**.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I only want to add that audit.log will hold messsages of SELinux only if auditd service is up, otherwise the messages will be in /var/log/message. And if some one have troubles with using sealert (like me) so you may to install selools-gui package. It will add "SELinux Audit Log Analizer" to System -> Administration. Remember to do: File -> Open Log -> /var/log/audit/audit.log